# Find all entities where all of their attributes values are within the attribute values of another entity

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

Consider the following table:

```
partyId PartyName   AttributeId
------- ----------  -----------
200167  Customer1   6444
200167  Customer1   6443
200167  Customer1   6442
200112  Customer2   6443
200133  Customer3   6443
200133  Customer3   6442
200155  Customer4   6449
200155  Customer4   6442
```

Customer1 has a set of AttributeId's associated with it.  I'll refer to this as Customer1's attribute set.  Customers 2 and 3 have attribute sets that are completely *within* Customer1's attribute set.  Customer 4 however, has one of its attributes that is not within Customer1's attribute set (attributeId 6449).  I am trying to write a SQL query that will yield a distinct list of parties where the party's entire attribute set is within customer1's attribute set, and that excludes all customers whose entire set is not within customer1's attribute set.  In this example the result should be:

```
partyId PartyName  
------- ----------  
200112  Customer2
200133  Customer3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following uses aggregation and counts the number of attributes for a given customer that match customer 1:

```
select t.customerid
from t left join
     t t1
     on t1.attributeid = t.attributeid and
        t1.customerid = 'Customer1'
group by t.customerid
having count(t.customerid) = count(t1.customerid);
```

Comment: Thanks, Gordon.  Exactly what I needed!